# How to skip the first element in an array?

Tags: jekyll

Is it possible in Jekyll to skip the first element of a list. For instance, if my page.url is /blog/1/2/3/4, I'd like to get just 1/2/3/4 by doing something like `{{ page.url | split:'/' | skip:'1'| join:'/' }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ended up finding my own answer:

```
page.url | split:'/' | slice:2,10 | join:'/'
```

Comment: so 10 is always bigger than the length of the array, but if there's something cleaner I'd love to know it

Comment: `{% assign c = page.myUrl | remove_first:"/" | split: "/" | shift | join:'/' %}`

Comment: @DavidJacquel ok so based on your comment I managed to achieve it using shift... twice! I guess there was an empty element at the beginning of the array? Here's the working line: `{{ page.url | split:'/' | shift | shift | join:'/' }}`

Comment: Use `assign` to debug. `{% assign myArray = page.url | split: "/" %}{{ myArray | inspect }}`

Comment: Not sure how inspect would work, I don't have the toolchain locally, I'm just using github pages... in any case if you add shift as an answer I'll accept it